# script to delete folders based on date

Tags: windows, rmdir

I've done some looking but just can't find the exact code. What I have is a series of server backups that are backed up to a remote location. I need a way to have a windows script that runs each night for this remote location server and deletes files based on the number of days I need to keep.

Each night a script based backup is done with a unique file name using the %random% tag. I need to keep, for example, the last 20 days worth of backups, and delete the rest

I looked at the "forfiles" but that delete's all files after a certain number of days inside all sub folders.

I just need a simple script that looks at the date of main folder (directory) in a given folder. It removes and deletes that folder and all subfolders based on the date.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each backup is in one folder then this will skip the newest 20 folders and delete the rest.  Remove the echo keyword to activate the rd command.

You can add /t:c to the DIR command to use folder creation time.  See DIR /? for options.

```
@echo off
pushd "d:\backup" && (
for /f "skip=20 delims=" %%a in ('dir /a:d /o:-d /b') do echo rd /s /q "%%a"
)
pause
```

By way of an explanation for those needing help understanding how the commands in this script work:

`pushd` sets the current directory to the specified path *"d:\backup"*

`for f/` a "for loop" that will iterate through the set of data according to the listed criteria

> `skip=20 delims=` skips the first 20 lines of file names (unparsed) that are returned in the directory
>
> *dir /a:d /o:-d /b*
> `dir` displays a list of directories
> `/a:d` looks only at folders in the directory (ignores files)
> `/o:-d` sorts/orders the resulting set of folders by date & time, newest to oldest
> `/b` presents set in bare format, meaning it only brings back the file names

*rd /s /q*
`rd` removes the directory
`/s` deletes all contents in a directory, both files and sub-directories
`/q` quiet mode, does not prompt for confirmation when deleting

Answer (score 0):

Use [`forfiles`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx) combined with an if check

You need a statement like

`ForFiles /P "PATH TO FOLDERS"  /D -20 /C "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE rmdir @FILE"`